# How do I compile LESS code using Brackets?

Tags: css, less, adobe-brackets

I use Brackets as my text editor. How can I compile and convert my LESS code into CSS?

The following is a link from where I downloaded the LESS compiler but I don't know how to convert my code into CSS.

https://github.com/jdiehl/brackets-less-autocompile

Comment: Follow the instructions carefully, and please check if Node JS is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install less-autocompile extension directly in Brackets using the second icon at the right of the editor. (I guess you are using last version of Brackets).

By default, when you save a less file, it will look for every .less file and compile them to .css files. 
If you want to produce a single .css file, you'll have to add lines at the top of your less files.

Comment: Will this work? <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.1/less.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/trial.less">

Comment: You have two solutions.

1. You compile your .less files into .css files and in your index.html you provide your css files with <link> markup
2. You add the script you show me above in your index.html, you provide your .less files with <link> markup and the compilation will happen when someone open index.html